# Updating the state of an array on React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am having problems with the response data I get from an API. I use axios to get the JSON object, and the state should be replaced by the list of objects every time the API is called.

Here is the code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHXn0.png

And here is the console

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnHD2.png

I imagine I am updating the state wrong, but I cant see what it is.

Comment: can you post the code instead of images?

Solution to your problem is not mutating the array.

Comment: You should have a code example and not screenshots. In order to answer this question you're making people write out your code for you. You shouldn't user a `push` use `return` per the `Array.prototype.map` specs.

Comment: you're misunderstanding what `map` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is pretty clear.

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

What does that mean? it means you called the method push on a variable that is still undefined

```
let paineis = empresas.map( (empresa, i) => {
    paineis.push(<Painel key={i} nome={empresa.nome} usuarios={empresa.usuarios} />)
//  ^-----^
//  this is the issue. paineis has not yet been assigned a value!
})
```

The real issue here is you are using `map` incorrectly. the return value in a map is the way to `push` a new value. You want to do this instead

```
let paineis = empresas.map( (empresa, i) => <Painel key={i} nome={empresa.nome} usuarios={empresa.usuarios} />)
```

this is an ES6 shorthand for a return, also could be written

```
let paineis = empresas.map( (empresa, i) => {
  return <Painel key={i} nome={empresa.nome} usuarios={empresa.usuarios} />
})
```

Comment: Fixed the function the way you showed me, and also tried using forEach and both lead to only rendering one <Painel /> component

Comment: @ericnr you may not be setting the state correctly. [see this fiddle for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fvz6j1ew/3/)

Comment: that worked, thanks! Now I am putting the api call in a setInterval so that it updates every 30 seconds but it gives me this error 

"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'empresas' of undefined" in the setState line. 

I need to replace the current array with a new one every time it the api is called but I dont know how to go by doing it.